# How can I verify an ID Token through Firebase Authentication REST API?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I have a backend server created in a language that does not support any of Firebase ADM SDK languages (java, Python, Node.js,Go, C#) .  So after the app client get the ID Token from Firebase Authentication, it sends this ID Token to the backend and then it will be necessary to validate this ID Token.

By checking deeply Firebase Documentation I could not find a reference for any Firebase API that performs such ID Token verification. It only refers to Firebase ADM SDK methods.

My questions are :

a) Is that possible to verify thi ID Token through a REST API provided by Firebase Authentication services ?

b) What APIT/Endpoint is avalilabe for that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) on the matter.

> **Verify ID tokens using a third-party JWT library**
>
> If your backend is in a language not supported by the Firebase Admin
> SDK, you can still verify ID tokens. First, [find a third-party JWT
> library for your language](https://jwt.io/). Then, verify the header, payload, and
> signature of the ID token.

The token is just a JWT.  You can use any library that understands how to process a JWT.  There is no need to call an endpoint.  You will have to write code to examine the contents of the JWT as further described in the linked documentation.

Comment: thks for the quick answer. I had already check that, but in fact I'd prefer to make a simple call to an REST API to verify this, than to import an external lib and implement on my code, at least for a while.  Does Firebase provide such REST API ?

Comment: There is no such API.  (If there was, it would be been mentioned in that documentation.)

Comment: thks Doug. So, btw do you know some way to embbed Firebase Admin SDK into a backend coded in Delphi ?